# EXCEL formula to reference cell in same row

Tags: excel-formula, office-2016

I want to apply conditional formatting to a cell when another cell in the same row is TRUE. I know how to do this with individual conditional formatting but I want to complete the objective with one rule.

EG. if G1 is true then A1 should be greenand so on for every row.

[image: Example]

Comment: `=G1` is the formula you apply to the full column.  Excel will iterate the row appropriately.

Comment: Better use `=$G1`, because that can be applied to other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a rule for one cell, you can apply that rule to other cells, too.

**Method 1:** 
Select the cell with the format, then click Home ribbon > Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules. In the dialog that opens, find the rule and adjust the range in the "Applies to" dialog. Make sure that the formula uses a reference that is relative for the row number, for example `=$G1` in row 1, then apply to other rows.

**Method 2:**
Select the cell with the format, click the format painter icon on the home ribbon, then select the cells to which you want to apply the format.

**Method 3:**
Use a table for your data. When you define a conditional format for a column, all new rows will inherit the format (and formulas and data validation) for that column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This seems compare G1 for every row. I would like A2 to check G2, A3 to check G3 etc.

Comment: Use relative referencing, without the $ sign in the conditional format, as mentioned in the comments to your question. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with VB instead. I checked the checkbox for a tick and then changed the colour of the cell 2 to the left of the tickbox.

```
Sub CheckBox_Colour_Checker()
Dim xChk As CheckBox
Set xChk = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
With xChk.TopLeftCell.Offset(, -2)
    If xChk.Value = xlOn Then
     .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
 Else
     .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you adding hundreds of check boxes to hundreds of rows of data? That is really reinventing the wheel and using hand-rolled solutions that are more cumbersome to set up and much slower to process than built-in conditional formatting.

Comment: Yes there is hundreds of rows and this solution meant that I didn't have to create the rule hundreds of times.

Comment: You don't need to create hundreds of rules. You only need one rule that applies to hundreds of rows. It's built into Excel. That's what the "conditional" in conditional formatting does.